# React: How to trigger event in parent component when onClick event happened in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following parent and child components. I want to run the `changeBackground` function every time the `button` in the child component (`<NewQuoteButton />`) is clicked but I don't know how to pass this information to the parent component. Can anyone please help?

```
//parent component

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state ={
      primary: '',
      prmaryDark: ''
    }
  }

  changeBackground = () => {

    let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*backgroundColors.length)
      this.setState = {
        primary: backgroundColors[randomNum].main,
        prmaryDark: backgroundColors[randomNum].dark
      }
    }
  

  render() { 
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <QuoteBox />
    </div>
    );
  }
}

//child component

export default function QuoteBox() {

    const [newQuote, setNewQuote] = useState('');
    const [author, setAuthor] = useState('');

    const fetchRandomQuote = () => {
    fetch(url)

    // some method
  }

  return (
    <div className="QuoteBox" >
        <Text quoteText={newQuote} author={author}  />
        <Banner>
            <Links />
            <NewQuoteButton onClick={fetchRandomQuote} className="NewQuoteButton Button" />
        </Banner>
    </div>
    );
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//parent component

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state ={
      primary: '',
      prmaryDark: ''
    }
  }

  changeBackground = () => {

    let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*backgroundColors.length)
      this.setState = {
        primary: backgroundColors[randomNum].main,
        prmaryDark: backgroundColors[randomNum].dark
      }
    }
  

  render() { 
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <QuoteBox handleColorChange={this.changeBackground} />
    </div>
    );
  }
}

//child component

export default function QuoteBox(props) {

    const [newQuote, setNewQuote] = useState('');
    const [author, setAuthor] = useState('');

    const fetchRandomQuote = () => {
props.handleColorChange();
    fetch(url)

    // some method
  }

  return (
    <div className="QuoteBox" >
        <Text quoteText={newQuote} author={author}  />
        <Banner>
            <Links />
            <NewQuoteButton onClick={fetchRandomQuote} className="NewQuoteButton Button" />
        </Banner>
    </div>
    );
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run your changeBackground function when the button is clicked then call the function in your fetchRandomQuote function.

Comment: I wanted to but this function should apply some styles to the App component so I can't execute it in the fetchRandomQuote function (as far as I am aware) because it is declared in the child component.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're not using function based components?

Comment: No, I am a React beginner so everything feels new to me. Why should I use function based components instead of the class ones in this example?

Comment: Class based components is the old way of doing react. You want to learn the current way which is function based components and use context API. You would be able to easily pass any prop to any component without having to do prop drilling. You would only have to use class based compnenets if you were working on legacy code.